# I am trying to make popup form using angular material, but catching some error

Tags: angular

**post.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="" (ngSubmit)="postForm.valid && onLogin()" novalidate>
  <div class="example-container">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
      <input id="title"
            matInput 
            formControlName="title"
            [(ngModel)]="post.title" 
            placeholder="Enter your title"/>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
      <textarea id="description" 
            matInput 
            formControlName="description" 
            [(ngModel)]="post.description" 
            placeholder="What on your mind?">
      </textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <button (click)="onNoClick()" class="button-row" mat-stroked-button color="accent">Cancel</button> 
      <button (click)="onCreate()" mat-stroked-button color="accent" >Post</button> 
    </mat-toolbar-row> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Actually the error is point me to line no 3 and line 12. And the next problem is textarea placeholder is not working

**post.component.ts**

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

  post: PostModel = new PostModel();
  postForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PostComponent>) { }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.postForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'title':[this.post.title,[
        Validators.required
      ]],    
      'description':[this.post.description,[
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(1000)
      ]]
    });    
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }    
}
```

Note: The post component is inside home component. Actually it is the nested component.

**My errors**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGGmR.png)

Comment: will you please create stackblitz for this so that we can understand your problem more easily

Comment: use of ``ngModel`` with ``formControlName`` is deprecated

Comment: @Pashupati  `[formGroup]="postForm "` add this one in html and why you are using `template driven` and `reactive` both in same time?

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Such a silly mistake. I appreciate your help

Comment: @PashupatiPariyar which one is work for you?

Comment: @Abhishek as per your suggestion i am using only reactive form. Thank you so much.

Comment: @PashupatiPariyar welcome